# brownie TransactionReceipt.wait(n) which value to avoid front run with geth?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, brownie, evm

I am new to these Ethereum topics and I was wondering how confirmations work and why the value can change?

And the other question is if I have my own GETH node what value should I put to avoid the front run if I mine my own transaction this should be enough and I understand the value should be 1?

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And the other question is if I have my own GETH node what value should I put to avoid the front run if I mine my own transaction this should be enough and I understand the value should be 1?

You are unlikely to be able to mine your own transaction unless you have considerable hashing power, worth of millions of dollars. Also confirmation value has nothing to with frontrunning.

[To avoid frontrunning, instead set slippage parameter for your trades](https://tradingstrategy.ai/docs/glossary.html#term-Slippage).

Comment: Ok thanks for the response now i undestand i thought that having my own node will help but no i undestand that unless i have a lot of computing power there is nothing to do.